# Can we use "Postponed" word for Library Book extension?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Today, my teacher asked me to postponed his books from library.
But i did not understand his meaning. All i think is, he wants his book's extension from library.

Please put light on it about the word "postponed". Is it correct? 
Postponed mean to delay but i think it is not used for book extension.
What other words can be used for Book extension? 
Looking forward to get good answer.

Comment: In the UK, we use the term *renewal*. You *renew* your loan. Of course, you can also *extend* the loan. It means the same thing.

Comment: Then What about "Postponed"? 
Postponed loan or Postponed book does not make any sense.

Comment: The return date is postponed.

Comment: The return date is postponed. yes makes sense. 
So, he means that renew his books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't say that we *postpone* the renewal date for something like a library book.  Instead (as Mick says) you should either *renew* the book, or *extend* the loan to the later date.

Comment: yes. i am agree too. I will clear this to my teacher. thank you